# Как protected модификатор влияет на выполнение программы тут?

Tags: java

Вот есть такой короткий код

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B(6);
}

public static class A {
    private int f1 = 7;

    public A(int f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        initialize();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    protected int f1 = 3;

    public B(int f1) {
        super(f1);
        this.f1 += f1;
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
}
```

В данном случае программа выведет 6 и 9 в консоль

Вот почти такой же код

```
public class Solution {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new B(6);
}

public static class A {
    private int f1 = 7;

    public A(int f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}

public static class B extends A {
    protected int f1 = 3;

    public B(int f1) {
        super(f1);
        this.f1 += f1;
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize() {
        System.out.println(f1);
    }
}
}
```

Только теперь программа выводит 0 и 9

Разница только в модификаторе доступа метода `initialize()` класса `class A` в одном случае это `privat` в другом `protected`.

Я сделал дебаг и не пойму почему в случае когда стоит `protected` программа предсказуемо создает обьект класса `B` потом идет в конструктор класса `А` присваевает значение для `f1` идет в метод `initialize()` класса `class A` и от туда почему то перепрыгивает в `initialize()` класса `class В` и печатает `0`.

То есть не пойму почему она прыгает в класс потомок. Я так понимаю `0` она печатает потому, что еще не проинициализирована.

Вот что говориться о `protected`

> Если метод или поле имеют модификатор доступа protected, то они, прежде всего, доступны самому классу и его наследникам. Кроме того, доступ к этим членам класса могут получить их собратья по пакету.

Почему программа идет за вызовом этого метода из класса `A` в класс `B`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Во-первых, в объекте `B` имеется два поля — `B.f1` (дочернее) и `A.f1` (родительское). У них разные значения. Так как поля в Java всегда невиртуальные, метод `B.initialize()` выводит всегда значение `B.f1`, а `A.initialize()` — значение `A.f1`. Если в `B.initialize()` вы хотите доступиться к родительскому полю с тем же именем, можно написать

```
protected void initialize() {
    System.out.println(f1);
    System.out.println(super.f1);
}
```

Вы увидите, что выводится разное значение. Но вообще очень не рекомендуется объявлять поле с тем же именем, что и неприватное поле родительского класса: это сбивает с толку и приводит к ошибкам. Объявите в дочернем классе `f2`, и всё станет понятнее.

С полями разобрались, теперь с методами. В Java методы и их вызовы обычно виртуальные. Это означает, что если в дочернем классе метод переопределён, то, когда кто угодно (в том числе родительский класс) вызывает данный метод, будет вызван по факту соответствующий метод из дочернего класса. Однако одно из исключений — это приватный метод. Приватный метод не может быть виртуальным. С точки зрения дочернего класса приватного метода родительского класса просто не существует (он не виден), поэтому дочерний класс волен называть свой метод тем же именем и они будут полностью независимы. Когда у вас в классе `A` метод `initialize` приватный, его вызовы становятся невиртуальными (вызывается всегда конкретно метод `A.initialize`). А когда вы его делаете protected, вызовы становятся виртуальными и если метод переопределён в дочернем классе, вызовется дочерний метод.

Такое поведение может показаться странным новичку, но оно исключительно важно для обратной совместимости. Представьте, вы наследуете библиотечный класс `A`, в котором нет метода `initialize`. Вы для своих целей определили в дочернем классе метод `B.initialize()` и используете его. Теперь авторы библиотеки решили её улучшить и часть кода вынести в новые методы. Удобство Java в том, что в родительском классе `A` они могут создавать любые новые приватные поля и методы без риска сломать дочерние классы или свой класс. То есть сейчас авторы библиотеки могут создать приватный метод `A.initialize()` и спокойно вызывать его. Это будет лично их дело, никто из наследников не заметит, что появился новый метод, даже если у наследников уже есть метод с тем же именем, который делает что-то совсем другое.

Comment: С методами понял и вспомнил) Точно, забыл, что вызываются дочерние методы. Только вот с переменной не совсем разобрался... Как в классе В 2 переменные f1? Я вижу обьявленную f1 с присваеваемым ей значением 3 и одну переменную которая  передается как параметр в конструкторе... Но они не связаны между собой, разве только в этой строке `this.f1 += f1;` ... Я так понимаю, что `0` получается из за того, что переменная не успевает проинициализироваться... Хотя вроде как должна, так как значение 3 ей присваевается явно...

Comment: Во втором примере у вас цепочка вызовов "конструктор B()" -> "конструктор А()" -> "присвоение A.f1 в конструкторе A" -> "виртуальный вызов B.initialize()" -> "вывод B.f1" -> "возврат из конструктора A()" -> "присвоение B.f1 в конструкторе B" -> "виртуальный вызов B.initialize()" -> "вывод B.f1". Как видите, у вас два раза выводится `B.f1`, причём при первом выводе оно ещё не инициализировано. Переменная `A.f1` не выводится вообще.

Comment: Ну как же тогда мы получаем `6` если `A.f1` не выводится вообще? Я так понимаю, что именно в классе А выводится эта переменная...

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko 6 выводится в первом вашем примере, а я говорил про второй (где всё private).

Answer (score 2):

Отвечу на ваш вопрос

> С методами понял и вспомнил) Точно, забыл, что вызываются дочерние методы. Только вот с переменной не совсем разобрался... Как в классе В 2 переменные f1? Я вижу объявленную f1 с присваеваемым ей значением 3 и одну переменную которая передается как параметр в конструкторе... Но они не связаны между собой, разве только в этой строке this.f1 += f1; ... Я так понимаю, что 0 получается из за того, что переменная не успевает проинициализироваться... Хотя вроде как должна, так как значение 3 ей присваевается явно...

В классе B нет двух переменных f1. Есть f1 - член B и f1 - член A. К f1-члену A из B можно получить доступ только через super.f1 и только потому что два класса находятся в одном файле (это исключительная ситуация и "не канон"). Важно понимать, что private - члены не участвуют в наследовании и являются исключительно свойствами класса, в котором определены. Изменив видимость метода на protected вы "включили" процедуру переопределения в дочернем классе и при вызове

```
public A(int f1) {
        this.f1 = f1;
        initialize();
    }
```

будет вызываться уже переопределённый метод initialize() из B (отсюда и 0).

Отсюда мораль: **не вызывайте в конструкторе переопределяемые методы** (не private и не final)